# How to specify two numbers in multidimensional array and return 'id' value

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my array (I think I have written it correct):

```
var data = {
  0 : {'id':754,'word':'hello'},
  1 : {'id':324,'word':'bye'},
  2 : {'id':111,'word':'nice'}
}
```

I'd like to specify one or two 'id's, e.g. `var nums = [324, 111];`

and have the script return what 'id' was not in `nums`, and therefore the output would be **754**

How can I do this?

PS. I wasnt sure how to title this

Comment: do you really need the structure to be an object with what appears to be array indexes as keys? If not change the server source to deliver an array and it will make your life easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```js
var data = {
  0 : {'id':754,'word':'hello'},
  1 : {'id':324,'word':'bye'},
  2 : {'id':111,'word':'nice'}
};
var nums = [324, 111];

//function for get the values
function getValues(data, nums){
  var output = [];

  for (var i in data){
    if (nums.indexOf(data[i].id)==-1)
      output.push(data[i].id);
  }
  return output;
}

document.write(getValues(data,nums)); //calling the function
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays like that should be declared like so:

```
var data = [{'id':754,'word':'hello'},
        {'id':324,'word':'bye'},
        {'id':111,'word':'nice'}];
```

That way you can use the new Array prototype functions like [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```
var excludedIds = [324, 111];

var objectsWithoutExcluded = data.filter(function(item){
  return excludedIds.indexOf(item.id) > 0;
});
```

And there you go.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this entirely using lodash (which is basically underscore).

```js
var data = {
  0 : {'id':754,'word':'hello'},
  1 : {'id':324,'word':'bye'},
  2 : {'id':111,'word':'nice'}
};

function getValues (data, excludedIDs) {
    var allIDs = _.pluck(data, 'id');
    return _.difference(allIDs, excludedIDs);
}

document.write(getValues(data,[324,111]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert `data` to an array using **[Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)**.
2. **[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** the output.
3. **[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** the filtered results to the ids.

**Code:**

```js
function missing(nums) {
  return Object.keys(data)
    .filter(function(n) {
      return nums.indexOf(data[n].id) === -1;
    })
    .map(function(n) {
      return data[n].id;
    });
} //missing

var data = {
  0 : {'id':754,'word':'hello'},
  1 : {'id':324,'word':'bye'},
  2 : {'id':111,'word':'nice'}
}

alert(missing([324, 111])); //754
alert(missing([]));         //754, 324, 111
alert(missing([111, 754])); //324
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data were an array instead, this would work:

```
data.filter(function(datum) {
    return nums.indexOf(datum.id) < 0;
}).map(function(datum) {
    return datum.id;
}); 
//=> [754]
```

With your current (somewhat odd, I might add) data structure, you might use this:

```
Object.keys(data).filter(function(key) {
    return nums.indexOf(data[key].id) < 0;
}).map(function(key) {
    return data[key].id;
});
```

I library like **[Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/)** might make this more concise:

```
R.map(R.prop('id'), R.reject(R.pipe(R.prop('id'), R.flip(R.contains)(nums)), data));
//=> [754]
```

(this is for the array case; I haven't thought through the other one.)

Answer (score -2):

Nest your Array like this.

```
var data = {
  0 : {'id': {value1: 324, value2: 111},'word':'hello'},   
}
```

Comment: you say nest array, but there is no array in your structure and trying to scale this would be very ugly. The `word` doesn't even match for both in OP data

Comment: Now I'm getting the hang of answering in Stackoverflow. Thanks. Next time I will answer in detail even if it's 4:30am lol